# bootstrap modal in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following weird problem in my rails app. I am using bootstrap modal to edit student information in my student model.

```
<td><%= link_to t('edit'), edit_student_path(student),
      {remote: true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 
        'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %>
</td>

div class="modal fade modal8" id="modal-window" tabindex="-1"
   role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The modal works as written above but does not work if I change the data-target and id of the modal from 'modal-window' to anything else. What is going on?

Comment: Update: The Problem was in a .js file that I was not updating

Answer (score 1):

`data-target` in anchor should be `css selector` and in modal `div` you should have that selector.

you are changing either one of them so it is not working,

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I am changing both at the same time

Comment: what are you putting in it ?

Comment: 'modal-window2' for example

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/passionateboy/g4xjyogk/ . Can you replicate this issue in jsfiddle

Comment: The problem was on the js file that calls the remote content. Thanks for your effort though